# what is the significance of 'useArrows:true'?

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        renderTo:'tree-div',
        title: 'My Task List',
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        useArrows:true,
        autoScroll:true,
        animate:true,
        enableDD:true,
        containerScroll: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        frame: true,
        root: {
            nodeType: 'async'
        },
```

In the above code,what is the significance of `useArrows:true`? Is it the property(builtin) to display the tree structure with arrows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see the `useArrows: true` causes the tree to be rendered using *Vista-style* arrows instead of +/- signs and lines in the folder nesting.

**From TreePanel.js**:

```
// private
onRender : function(ct, position){
    Ext.tree.TreePanel.superclass.onRender.call(this, ct, position);
    this.el.addClass('x-tree');
    this.innerCt = this.body.createChild({tag:'ul',
           cls:'x-tree-root-ct ' +
           (this.useArrows ? 'x-tree-arrows' : this.lines ? 'x-tree-lines' : 'x-tree-no-lines')});
},
```

**From the ExtJS API**:

> **useArrows** : *Boolean*
>   true to use Vista-style arrows in the tree (defaults to false)